# Nested UDTs with different lenghts

Tags: excel, vba

Hello beautiful people,

I am trying to create nested UDTs in vba in such a way that the child UDT can have multiple instances depending on the case.

The example below explains better what I am trying to do:

Sample data:

```
+----------+-------------+
| Customer | Transaction |
+----------+-------------+
| A        |           1 |
| B        |           2 |
| C        |           3 |
| C        |           4 |
| C        |           5 |
| D        |           6 |
| E        |           7 |
| F        |           8 |
| D        |           9 |
| E        |          10 |
+----------+-------------+
```

Desired results:

- customer(1).transaction(1).transactionid = 1
- customer(2).transaction(1).transactionid = 2
- customer(3).transaction(1).transactionid = 3
- customer(3).transaction(2).transactionid = 4
- customer(3).transaction(3).transactionid = 5
- customer(4).transaction(1).transactionid = 6
- customer(4).transaction(2).transactionid = 9
- customer(5).transaction(1).transactionid = 7
- customer(5).transaction(2).transactionid = 10
- customer(6).transaction(1).transactionid = 8

I initially tried using classes as there are many variable I need to keep track of for each 'instance' of the UDTs. However, due to my data being too large, using classes was taking too long (a couple of minutes).

Switching to UDTs reduced my runtime to a couple of seconds but some adjustments were necessary.

As I understand, I can pass multiple 'instances' of a UDT in the manner I am trying to do, but I should do so as an filled array of undefined lenght. I can't really wrap my head around this, though, at least not enough to come up with a solution.

Do I need to loop through all my data n-times creating n arrays (n=6 in the example)?
This would take a heavy toll on performance. Is there a more elegant solution?

The below code is what I have been using in my latest attempts.

```
Option Explicit

Public Type Child
    transactionid As String
    det As String
End Type
Public Type Parent
    children As Child
End Type

Sub test()

ReDim transaction(1 To 10) As Child
ReDim customer(1 To 6) As Parent

Dim wk As Worksheet
Set wk = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)


Dim c As Integer
For c = 1 To 10
    transaction(c).det = wk.Range("G" & c + 1).Value
    transaction(c).transactionid = wk.Range("h" & c + 1).Value
Next c

Dim j As Integer
Dim i As Integer
j = 1
For i = 1 To 6
    If customer(i).children(j).transactionid <> "" Then
        'I don't even know
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

I get a

> compile error "Expected array"

in

```
customer(i).children(j).transactionid
```

Comment: You  didn't define children as an array it would need to be ```children() As Child```, though I'm not convinced that is the only issue. As an aside, using classes shouldn't be jacking up your runtime that much, I've used classes in huge datasets with no issues.

Comment: Hi Warcupine. I belive this adjustment is indeed a step in the right direction. I now get a 'subscript out of range' error message. Regarding using classes, I had around 100k instances and only changing between a dictionary of class objects and UDT my runtime went from 133s to 3s.

Comment: Subscript out of range is because the index of the array is not an empty string it doesn't exist because it hasn't been assigned a value. If you want to check if it is empty you would need to set the maximum index of children on declaration or leave it open and assign an empty string to each index.

Comment: If I set the maximum index at declaration I won't be able to pass it on, right? As to assigning an empty string, that would still raise the error when going to the next child of each parent, right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by not able to pass it on. If you ```dim children(10)``` that creates an array with 11 elements in it, index 0 - 10. If you assign an empty string to all the indices you plan on using there wouldn't be a subscript out of range error because you are only using indices which have values (though this is 
a sloppy way of doing it and I don't really recommend it).

Comment: I get your point but for that I would need to know how many children there are for each parent. I worry that would create too much additional work as the only way I see it would be to loop through my dataset multiple times.

Comment: Yeah that probably is the only way to do that. Like @tigeravatar said without knowing what your end goal is it is hard to say what the best way is. That answer has a nested loop, so if there are a ton of customers and a ton of transactions per customer you end up iterating millions and millions of times. Just looping through a sheet with  100k rows and storing the values in a dictionary should only take maybe 2 seconds, probably less.

Comment: Yeah, I found a solution to a similar problem by sorting in such a manner that I could loop only once through the data, but I couldn't think of anything applicable in this case. I expanded more on my end goal on @tigeravatar's answer, so if you have anything to contribute, I would be deeply grateful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary for this, no UDT or custom class needed.  If you really want to use one of those we could make it work with a similar concept, but here's how you'd do it with a dictionary, as well as how to iterate through everything in the dictionary to get the info.  It should populate the dictionary pretty quickly too:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

    With ws.Range("G2", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp))
        If .Row < 2 Then Exit Sub   'No data

        Dim aData() As Variant
        aData = .Value
    End With

    Dim hCustomers As Object
    Set hCustomers = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Dim i As Long
    Dim hTemp As Object
    For i = LBound(aData, 1) To UBound(aData, 1)
        If Not hCustomers.Exists(aData(i, 1)) Then
            Set hTemp = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        Else
            Set hTemp = hCustomers(aData(i, 1))
        End If
        hTemp(hTemp.Count + 1) = aData(i, 2)
        Set hCustomers(aData(i, 1)) = hTemp
        Set hTemp = Nothing
    Next i

    Dim vCustomer As Variant
    Dim vTransactionID As Variant
    For Each vCustomer In hCustomers.Keys
        For Each vTransactionID In hCustomers(vCustomer).Keys
            MsgBox "Customer: " & vCustomer & Chr(10) & _
                   "Transaction ID: " & vTransactionID & Chr(10) & _
                   "Transaction: " & hCustomers(vCustomer)(vTransactionID)
        Next vTransactionID
    Next vCustomer

End Sub
```

Comment: This worked beautifully for my sample data set of 10 entries. When I tried to apply it to my whole data, things changed. It took me 104s to run. That's over 20 times my whole applicatin run-time. Any ideia why this happens and how to circumvent it?

Comment: @saybhausd The biggest factor for time using this method is the number of unique customers.  When I used 1,000,000 rows of transactions with 17,576 unique customers, the code completed in 22 seconds.  When I increased the number of unique customers to 456,976 (still with a million total transactions), my computer actually ran out of memory.

Comment: @saybhausd So I guess the only way to optimize it from here is to find out what you actually want to do with the compiled information. What's your end goal here?

Comment: So, my dataset consists of 35k unique customers and 65k transactions. My project is a little on the large size, so I segmented it into two separate parts: creating the necessary data-structures and actually processing them. There are a lot of tests I need to run on the variables but for this specific one I need a flag at customer-level if any of his transactions happened in the current month. Other info I will try to gather at customer-level are total transactions amount, latest transaction date, etc.

Comment: I would do dictionary --> class1 with all the data that you need at customer level and a dictionary --> dictionary -->class2 with all the data that is at the transaction level. load the first date into class1 then compare to each new date and if greater load that instead, keep a running count of transactions in class1, and a boolean to flag if any date has happened this month. You can quickly access the class1 data and if need be access all data. It might take a moment to run but it shouldn't be that long, and would be only a single loop to load it and a single loop to extract it.

Comment: That seems promising, although I must admit I am not quite sure I fully comprehend the details. Your suggestion is nesting a dictionary of key:=Transaction, value:=Class(transaction info) as the value inside of a second dictionary where keys:=Customer? I don't really grasp where the two classes come into play.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so here is a rough idea of what I mentioned in the comments.

This is to load the data:

```
Sub test()
    Dim parentdict As Object

    Dim parentcls As Parent

    Dim iter As Long
    Dim lastrow As Long

    Dim customer As String
    Dim trans As Long
    Dim transdate As Date

    Set parentdict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")


    With ActiveSheet ' Use a real sheet name
        lastrow = .Cells(.rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).row
        For iter = 2 To lastrow
            customer = .Cells(iter, "A").value
            trans = .Cells(iter, "B").value
            transdate = .Cells(iter, "C").value
                If Not parentdict.Exists(customer) Then ' Populate Parent Dictionary
                    Set parentcls = New Parent
                    parentcls.initialize transdate
                    parentdict.Add customer, parentcls
                    parentdict(customer).addtrans trans, transdate
                Else
                    parentdict(customer).addtrans trans, transdate
                End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

This is the parent class:

```
Option Explicit

Private plasttrans As Date
Private pcurrentmonth As Boolean
Private ptotaltrans As Long
Private pchilddict As Object
Private childcls As Child

Public Property Get lasttrans() As Date
    lasttrans = plasttrans
End Property

Public Property Let lasttrans(llasttrans As Date)
    plasttrans = llasttrans
End Property

Public Property Get currentmonth() As Boolean
    currentmonth = pcurrentmonth
End Property

Private Sub togglecurrent()
    If pcurrentmonth = False Then
        pcurrentmonth = True
    Else
        pcurrentmonth = False
    End If
End Sub

Public Property Get totaltrans() As Long
    totaltrans = ptotaltrans
End Property

Public Sub addtrans(transaction As Long, transactiondate As Date)
    ptotaltrans = ptotaltrans + 1
    Set childcls = New Child
    childcls.transdate = transactiondate
    pchilddict.Add transaction, childcls
    If Month(transactiondate) = Month(Date) Then
        togglecurrent
    End If
    If transactiondate > plasttrans Then
        plasttrans = transactiondate
    End If

End Sub

Public Sub initialize(transactiondate As Date)
    Set pchilddict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    plasttrans = transactiondate
    pcurrentmonth = False
    ptotaltrans = 0
End Sub
```

And here is the child class (I only added in a single property):

```
Option Explicit

Private ptransdate As Date

Public Property Let transdate(ltransdate As Date)
    ptransdate = ltransdate
End Property

Public Property Get transdate() As Date
    transdate = ptransdate
End Property
```

The idea being you have a dictionary with Key:=Customer, Item:=Parent

Parent is a class containing everything at the customer level, so your current month flag, latest transaction, a running count of transactions, and another dictionary for transactions.

The transaction dictionary is Key:=transaction, Item:=Child

Child is a class containing everything at the transaction level. In my example that is just a date but you can add in dollar amounts or whatever else you will need. If you don't need anything else you could just use the dictionary in Parent and scrap the Child Class altogether.

You should then be able to access any transaction using the transaction number and the customer, or every transaction with a loop and customer.